# Can this Delphi code related to an array of function of object be made cleaner?

Tags: arrays, pointers, delphi

Regarding this function in Delphi:

```
function TAudioFileMetadata.LoadTags(const Filename: String; var LastError: Integer; var DetectedFormat: TAudioFormat): Boolean;
type
  TLoadFromFunction = function (const Filename: String; var LastError: Integer): Boolean of object;

  TLoadFrom = record
    Format: TAudioFormat;
    Process: TLoadFromFunction;
  end;

var
  i: Byte;
  LoadOrder: array [1..6] of TLoadFrom;

begin
  DetectedFormat := afUnknown;

  LoadOrder[1].Format := afMp3;
  LoadOrder[1].Process := LoadFromMp3;

  //...

  LoadOrder[6].Format := afApe;
  LoadOrder[6].Process := LoadFromApe;

  for i := Low(LoadOrder) to High(LoadOrder) do
  begin
    Result := LoadOrder[i].Process(Filename, LastError);
    if Result then
    begin
      DetectedFormat := LoadOrder[i].Format;
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

How can I improve my implementation? Can I create/fill the `LoadOrder` array in one shot (or at least not using 2 lines per `TLoadFrom`)? Could a `const` array be used (I don't think so)?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this code

Comment: *"Could a const array would be possible.."* - Yes, if you can use regular functions instead of methods. Methods cannot be resolved at compile time.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz however, it is possible to get the address of a class method at compile time. It is just the `Self` pointer that can't be. Use of `TMethod` might be able to solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Use of TMethod? How?

Comment: @AlexV see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi closures (`function|procedure ... of object`) are backed by the [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) record, which you can manipulate at runtime. So try something like this:

```
function TAudioFileMetadata.LoadTags(const Filename: String; var LastError: Integer; var DetectedFormat: TAudioFormat): Boolean;
type
  TLoadFromFunction = function (const Filename: String; var LastError: Integer): Boolean of object;

  TLoadFrom = record
    Format: TAudioFormat;
    ProcessAddr: Pointer;
  end;

const
  LoadOrder: array[1..6] of TLoadFrom = (
    (Format: afMp3; ProcessAddr: @TAudioFileMetadata.LoadFromMp3),
    ...
    (Format: afApe; ProcessAddr: @TAudioFileMetadata.LoadFromApe)
  );

var
  i: Byte;
  Process: TLoadFromFunction;

begin
  DetectedFormat := afUnknown;
  TMethod(Process).Data := Self;

  for i := Low(LoadOrder) to High(LoadOrder) do
  begin
    TMethod(Process).Code := LoadOrder[i].ProcessAddr;

    Result := Process(Filename, LastError);
    if Result then
    begin
      DetectedFormat := LoadOrder[i].Format;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This does, indeed, give answers to questions 2 and 3 (can the array be filled in one shot? - yes; and is a const array possible? - yes), but regarding question 1, 'can I improve my implementation?', I'd feel inclined to answer no - the original implementation is clearer. Not as a criticism of this useful answer, but just as a point to consider for the original poster.

Comment: @MatthiasB perhaps so. One way to "improve" the original code would be to simply move `LoadOrder` outside of `LoadTags()`, such as by making it a data member of `TAudioFileMetadata` that is initialized in the constructor.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I just found out that with this solution the signature in TLoadFromFunction can have extra params and it still work... I mean if I add an extra bool param an the end of TLoadFromFunction and the actual function don't have it, it still works. Why?

Comment: @AlexV `TMethod` uses a raw `Pointer`. The compiler can't validate that signature. It's your responsibility to match signatures. If you change the signature of the methods, you have to change `TLoadFromFunction`, and vice versa. You have to do this even in your original code, as the compiler would simply complain if they mismatch, but that is not the case when using `TMethod` directly. Adding more params to `TLoadFromFunction` but not to the methods would be very bad. The methods would *ignore the extra param values, and **not clean them up***, so you could end up with a corrupted call stack.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you for your help!